# Probability of having disease, given k positive tests from n total tests

Tags: probability

Jimmy decides to take a series of $n$ tests, to diagnose whether he has a certain disease (any individual test is not perfectly reliable, so he hopes to reduce his uncertainty by taking multiple tests). Let $D$ be the event that he has the disease, $p=P(D)$ be the prior probability that he has the disease, and $q=1-p$. Let $T_j$ be the event that he tests positive on the $j$th test.

Assume for this part that the test results are conditionally independent given Jimmy’s disease status. Let $a=P(T_j|D)$ and $b=P(T_j|D^c)$ , where a and b don’t depend on $j$. Find the posterior probability that Jimmy has the disease, given that he tests positive on exactly  $k$ out of the $n$ tests.

The answer is given below, I am trying to decompose it to understand the individual parts.

Let $X$ be the number of positive test results.

$P(D|X=k) = \frac{P(X=k|D)P(D)}{P(X=k)} = \frac{pa^k(1-a)^{n-k}}{pa^k(1-a)^{n-k}+qb^k(1-b)^{n-k}}$

So in the numerator, we get the $p$ because $P(D)=p$, that replaces one for one.

I don't understand the $a^k(1-a)^{n-k}$

$a^k$ is the probability of testing positive in $k$ tests given that he has the disease. $(1-a)^{n-k}$ is the probability that he tests negative given that he has the disease for the remaining tests.

So $a^k(1-a)^{n-k}=P(X=k|D)$, which is the probability of testing $k$ times positive while having the disease.

But we know the probability of testing positive while having the disease is $a^k$. So why are we adding  $(1-a)^{n-k}$ (probability that of negative test given that disease)?

Comment: It's a binomial distribution. The $\binom{n}{k}$ part has been already cancelled out from the top and bottom of your fraction

Comment: It seems optimistic to assume each test is independent of the others conditioned on the presence of the disease:  for example if Jimmy is worried about having influenza and tests this by measuring his temperature, then repeated tests may tell him the same thing each time but not provide much more information than a single test.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there are a few multipliers missing which might help to understand the cause of miscomprehension. First, whilst each of the tests are independent, they are also not ordered, so there must appear a binomial coefficient. Second, even though you're searching for $k$ successful tests, Jimmy *has to take* the total of $n$ tests in which there must be negative results, i.e. false positives and false negatives.

That said, let's figure out what $P(X=k|n,D)$ actually is. It is exactly the binomial distribution with the probability of success $a$ given $n$ trials. So:
$$
P(X=k|n,D) = \binom{n}{k} \cdot a^k \cdot (1-a)^{n-k}
$$
Similarly, the probability of obtaining the same number of successes given there is no disease is:
$$
P(X=k|n,D^c) = \binom{n}{k} \cdot b^k \cdot (1-b)^{n-k}
$$

Since $D$ and $D^c$ are disjoint, the total probabilty $P(X=k)$ is nothing but their sum, weighted by the probabilty of each event ($D$ or $D^c$):   $$P(X=k|n) = P(X=k|n,D) \cdot P(D) + P(X=k|n,D^c) \cdot P(D^c)$$

That brings us to the denominator:
$$
P(X=k|n) = 
 p \cdot \binom{n}{k} \cdot a^k \cdot (1-a)^{n-k} + 
 q \cdot \binom{n}{k} \cdot b^k \cdot (1-b)^{n-k} 
$$

When substituting that into the Bayes' rule, one obtains:
$$
P(D|X=k) = \frac{p \cdot \binom{n}{k} \cdot a^k \cdot (1-a)^{n-k}}{
 p \cdot \binom{n}{k} \cdot a^k \cdot (1-a)^{n-k} + 
 q \cdot \binom{n}{k} \cdot b^k \cdot (1-b)^{n-k} }
$$

Since $\binom{n}{k}$ factors out in the denominator, it cancels out with the same term in the numerator, yielding the answer you got:
$$
P(D|X=k) = \frac{p \cdot a^k \cdot (1-a)^{n-k}}
{p \cdot a^k \cdot (1-a)^{n-k} + q \cdot b^k \cdot (1-b)^{n-k} }
$$

#### Extra:

###### It would be curious to affirm the formula by some obvious cases:

1. $a=b$:
   That is the case of a random test; namely, the doctor could just toss an unbiased coin to confirm or reject having a disease. In this case all the factors containing the powers of $k$ cancel out leaving:
   $$
   P(D|X=k) = \frac{p}{p+q} = p
   $$
   which is itself rather logical. Since the test won't help us gain new knowledge about the disease, the outcome cannot depend on $k$ and out posterior knowledge is the same as our prior.
2. $b=0$:
   That is the case of an extremely confident test that never gives false positives. In that case, even one test guarantees certain knowledge about the disease:
   $$
   P(D|X=k)\vert_{k>0, b=0}=1
   $$
   In case $k=0$:
   $$
   P(D|X=0)\vert_{b=0}=\frac{p \cdot (1-a)^{n}}{p \cdot (1-a)^{n} + q}
   $$
   which states, that prior to any test we allow some possibility for the test to be misleading.